# Bot framework composer environment variables

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Is possible to load environment variables in bot framework composer.

Of course this is possible using the code version, however, I am wondering if and how it is done using bot composer. So far i've failed to find any documentation for it.

Usage is for example for external API call endpoints. E.g. Production, staging and develop environments.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in Composer itself. What you can do is have the runtime available for you to then do it via code.

In Composer go to `Settings-> Runtime Config-> Use custom runtime-> Get a new copy of the runtime code-> Add custom runtime`. That will create a folder with the runtime and you can make changes there.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can put custom settings into the `appsettings.json` file, and use them within Composer with `${settings.MySettingName}`.  See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8522).